# Ejabberd 1000 virtual host is possbile?

Tags: mysql, virtualhost, ejabberd

We are developing chat application with 1000 virtual host. Each virtual host one company. we are strugling more then 20 virtual host the server get slow some times server down. How many virtual host possbile in a single node. what is the configuration of server when adds 1000 virtual host.

OS : Centos 8
version: ejabberd20.04
database:MySql

It would be grate help any help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the OS would stumble all over itself trying to keep more than a dozen VMs happy.  (As you found with a mere 20.)  Is this a beefy machine?  I would go with a single server with a single instance of MySQL, and `company_id` as part of the `PRIMARY KEY` in many tables.

(This question might more traction in dba.stackoverflow.com.  This stackoverflow.com is oriented more toward coding.)

In comparison, MySQL, itself, maxes out at a hundred or so *really concurrent* queries.  A few thousand individuals chatting is no problem since they are not *really* concurrently doing anything.

With VM, you have these layers:

- OS coordinating the VMs
- Each VM coordinating the processes within it (MySQL, etc)
- Each MySQL coordinating the connections.

With a single MySQL instance:

- One OS, no VM OS.
- One MySQL.
- Lots of connections (not a big problem).
- The same number of *active* connections (rarely more than a dozen).

Furthermore, let's look at RAM usage.

- A single conversation will touch *maybe* one megabyte of data (chat conversations, indexes, etc).
- A VM loaded with MySQL (code, data, overhead, etc) may need upwards of a gigabyte.

That means that a thousand VMs might take a *terabyte* of RAM just for minimal usage.  Meanwhile, a consolidated chat platform for the same amount of traffic could be handled in (I estimate) about 4GB.

(If you have an ulterior reason for wanting to do VMs, say so.)